# Can I transfer DLC files between xbox ones using an external disk?

Tags: xbox-one

I have two Xbox Ones, one at home and one sitting at a friends house. I play a lot over there so we invested in an additional Xbox One at his house with its own screen.

This week The Division launched and with it came all my preorder DLCs. That is, almost.

At home I had a lot of DLC contents to install, including some special cosmetic outfit sets. Once the DLC has been downloaded, the clothing items are available from an ingame vendor for free. I downloaded them all at home, started the game, and claimed all my clothes, then equipped the ones I felt looked the best.

Then I visited my friends house for a gaming session and for some reason some of those DLC's are not available for download, in fact there is no trace of them in the store or in the "My Games and Apps" app at all, it's as if they don't exist.

So the game client on that Xbox One think those items doesn't exist, so my character lost those items, not only did I not wear the same clothing items any more, they're not in my inventory and not even at that vendor.

But lo and behold, back home I can visit the same vendor and claim them yet again.

But this gets tiresome.

So my question is this, before I go purchase an external disk or memory stick (I have none lying around that I either can use or that the Xbox One accepts), can I transfer DLC files from one Xbox One to another that will likely solve this?

Or are the DLC files bound to the Xbox One they was downloaded on? They are used by the same Xbox account / gamertag on both units so this is not about sharing the DLCs with someone else, just about getting them onto that other Xbox One.